# Use google plusone button (not share button) in a newsletter

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus, google-plus-one

Good morning folks.
I try to implement the Google "+1" button into a newsletter (they are also as static web version available) but I can't use javascript here.

Is there any way to do this without javascript? It's also possible to share a page via a static url from google:

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url=your-page-url
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered your own question by adding that link.
You'll have to create a "+1" image and embed it in your newsletter (remember to host the image on your servers and link it from there). Example:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=your-page-url">
    <img src="http://www.yoursite.com/images/plusone.jpg" />
</a>
```

where your-page-url is your page url (http://www.yourpace.com)

Comment: Please re-read my question. I don't want to "share" the page, I want to "+1" the page - these are different actions. I only mentioned that there is a static url for sharing stuff, but I couldn't find one for "+1" stuff.

Comment: Well, in that case, I'm afraid it's not possible, or at least I couldn't find it in their documentation. I think they made it like this because the +1 button doesn't open any other window or popup when you use it on the web (except for the share box), and since you can't use js in newsletters they decided to remove it completely in order to stay consistent with the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

No. The [JavaScript button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/) is the only supported method of +1'ing a URL. You can add a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/entry?template=Feature%20Request%20-%20Plugins).